# httaccess in Wordpress - point to subfolder + redirect to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

The old `.htaccess` redirects automatically to https protocol :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But I saw there is no pointer to the subfolder via htaccess. The ex-developper used this :

**[root]index.php**

```
<?php include_once("wordpress/index.php"); ?>
```

It seems to create several bugs :
on the admin panel side, there is a redirection `https://my-site/wp-admin/` to `https://my-site/wordpress/wp-admin/` but not on the front-end.
Sometimes on the admin side, there are some redirection like this : `https://my-site/wp-admin/...` which generates bugs.

So... It´s confusing and I wish to clean this with a simpler way : I would like :

1. point the domain to the subfolder `wordpress` and works for front-end and back-end
2. keep the automatic redirection http to https

I tried this without success :

**.htaccess**

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?docpeda.be$
     RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress/index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

I´m sure it´s really easy to do it but I need some helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you should put in the .htaccess file if it's a subfolder, hopefully this will solve your issue (just copy and paste). It will also make the site secure.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?docpeda.be$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?docpeda.be$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Where is the rule to point to the subfolder /wordpress/ ? I commented the code inside the [root]index.php to be cleaner.

Comment: Sorry but, that does not work in my context, I put your code in [root].htaccess inside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tag.

Comment: Check my edit please :) Don't add to your old .htaccess file, just rename your old one and create a new one and then just copy and paste mine

Comment: I would like to use ONLY the root .htaccess to do this but your alternative code seems to forget the automatic https redirection.

Comment: Yes, my code should be put in the /.htaccess folder and I've added another bit for the HTTPS (which is an easy fix). Although, if my fixes don't work, you may need to add a .htaccess file into your subsites folder as well.

Comment: `https://docpeda.be/` redirect to `https://docpeda.be/wordpress/` in Firefox and I have a blank page for Chrome. So, now, everything is wrong :/

Comment: Sorry but I did.

Comment: Did you create the .htaccess file in the subfolder?

Comment: Please, can you write the code only for the [root].httacces in one piece to be sure I did  what you´re saying ?

Comment: The .htaccess in the subfolder is mandatory ? Can I simplify with only [root].htaccess ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187433/discussion-between-ember-and-j-bizmai).